# Win10 isoburn - no burner options

Tags: windows-10, burning

Trying to burn an `.img` file:
[image]

No options under "Disc burner", even though I have a USB drive in.

Comment: 'burner' would imply it's looking for a CD/DVD drive, not a USB stick. Maybe try [ISO2USB](http://www.isotousb.com) instead?

Comment: The program you are attempting to work does not support creating USB removable drives.  **It only supports optical drives.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have noted in their comments, you're trying to do something with this software that it doesn't support.

This product writes CDs and other optical writable media. It does not write to anything else.

You need to find the correct software for what you're trying to do.